# Why does transmission adds a new user to the system?

Tags: linux, users, raspberry-pi

When I installed transmission, I've seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/221096) that I need to change the ownership of some groups to able this to work with my raspberry pi. First of all: why does transmission adds a new user to the system? I tried to set the downloads folder of transmission to my USB flash drive but I get a permission error. So I need to change who owns the folder of the pen drive, rigth? But who owns it? I just plugged my pen drive, I've never set nobody to own it.

Also, why he calls it "debian-transmission group". Isn't debian-transmission an user?

THe tutorial is basically saying I need to change the ownership of /media/MyPenDrive to the debian transmission user?

Then he says:

> grant write access to the group
>
> sudo chmod 770 /home/chen/TV\ shows

Isn't the group "debian-transmission"? Why is he granting write access to the folder?
When he grants access to a folder, he grants access to everybody who owns it? Shouldn't I be able to give different permissions to different users who can access the folder?

Answer (score 3):

You've asked a few questions.

> Why does installing transmission create a new user?

For security. Basically, by running Transmission as its own user, its ability to touch other users' data on the system (such as *your user*) is greatly limited. If there is a security flaw in Transmission, a cracker who exploited it would find it much more difficult, if not impossible, to steal, modify, etc. your private data.

> Isn't `debian-transmission` a user?

Yes, it is. It is a group as well. It's pretty common for a user to have a group with the same name (your user probably does too—check by running `id` for example).

> Changing the owner of the flash drive

How to do this depends on if the flash drive is formatted as FAT32 (Windows compatible) or ext2/3/4/btrfs/etc. FAT32 doesn't support permissions; the mount options specify which users and group own the files, and the permissions. You'll have to modify the configuration of whatever is mounting it (if its from `/etc/fstab`, that's easy: just add the `uid=`, `gid=`, etc. options; see "Mount options for fat" in the `mount(8)` manpage). If it is a Unix filesystem (like ext2/3/4, btrfs, etc.) then the `chgrp`, `chmod`, etc. will work.

Note: files and directories have both an owning *user* and an owning *group*. They can be different. If you've ever wondered why `ls -l` shows your username twice, the second one is actually that group with the same name.

In short, yes, you need the `debian-transmission` user or group to have `write` access to whatever directory (and files) it is going to save downloads to. You can also use POSIX ACLs (`setfacl`) to grant those permissions without changing the ownership, if supported by the filesystem (and all the common Linux one's support it).